# Can I create an Initial migration for an existing model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code-First migrations. Now I want my application when published to a new server to create a database and all tables for the model.

I don't want to use auto-migrations because I want to keep track of database versioning.
But when I deploy my application to a new server I don't want it to perform all steps to come to the current model (e.g adding tables/columns which in later revisions are deleted).

I would like to know if there is a way to create one migration that contains the whole (POCO) data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the connection string to target your new database, EF will look to compare your model, and it's migrations with what exists on the database. If nothing exists (new database) It will then create a database to match what you have, by implementing every migration in order for you.  If you wanted to see the generated sql before implementing, run:

```
update-database -verbose -script
```

In the package manager console and see what gets generated.

It will look something like:

- Create Table
- Insert Migration
- History Row Modify
- Table Insert
- Migration History Row
- etc...

Even if you have tons of migrations, it will combine them all into a single script and implement them all at once.

Comment: Hi Mark, This is not what I mean. I mean that I want to generate a migration class that only represents the current model. So I would like to throw away all existing migration classes and generate one big migration class, which adds all tables. The problem now is that I have lots of migrations, that are not relevant anymore, because they consist of modifications that have been discarded after refactoring.

Comment: If you don't need the migrations anymore - you can delete everything in the Migrations folder.  When you run the add-migration command, it will only generate the single script for you.

Comment: Yep, that is what I did. Unfortunately it does only generate an empty migration. When running the application, it does create the database but no tables except for _MigrationHistory

Comment: Did you change the connection string it's targeting? You either need to overwrite the default constructor, or change the original connection string.  Package manager console doesn't know if you're doing an overload using the YourContext("ConnectionString") if thats where you changed it.

Comment: Mark, you are a genius! Thanks, changing the connection string did the trick!